# Finding/advertising for GIS freelancers

Tags: freelancing

If I wanted to find/advertise for a freelancer to do a GIS job, and if I am not allowed to do it here, then where would be a good place?

I've advertised on [oDesk](https://www.odesk.com/) (which we use frequently), but it doesn't even have a GIS category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place job advertisements on the Stack Exchange network you can use [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) on which a [search by GIS](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=gis) should turn up some jobs.

Although jobs are not mentioned specifically, the [GIS Stack Exchange policy on advertising](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) generally is:

> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product
>   or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our
>   advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact)
>   for details.

A more specific discussion has occurred previously in Meta GIS Stack Exchange at [Can Job Ads be posted on GIS SE?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/job-ads-where-to-post) where you may find this [answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/588) useful because it suggests some other ways forward.